# Javascript Regex Replace Multiple Patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do a replace for every pattern that looks like either:

```
" - ", // space dash space
" ", // space
"*", // asterisk
```

and replace it with a space.

I tried:

```
const name = "Test - number one*"
const regExName = name.replace((\s-\s)|(-)|(\s)|(\*)/g, '_');
```

Obviously wrong... Help please?

Comment: `.replace(/ - |-| |\*/g, '_')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this pattern:

```
/ - | |\*/g
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQ8aO5/2)

---

And here is full code:

```js
const name = "Test - number one*"
const regExName = name.replace(/ - | |\*/g, '_');
document.write(regExName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the leading `/`:

```
name.replace(/(\s-\s)|(-)|(\s)|(\*)/g, '_');
             ^ here
```